# SHA256 function changes input variables

Tags: c, pointers, openssl, sha256

I just started using sha functions of OpenSSL under windows with vc2k10 and I've got a problem. since I couldn't find much detailed documentation about it I'm asking here:

the SHA256(const unsigned char *in, size_t n,unsigned char *out) function seems to change what in pointer points to. is this a bug or feature?
thanks

Comment: The problem is almost certainly **not** with the library. Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your in and out don't point to the same memory?

It's unlikely that there is  both a bug in the opensll lib and visual studio's implementation of const